# The irrationality of $\sqrt{3}$ and the fundamental theorem of arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do you prove the square root of $3$ is irrational by using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic?
We learned proof by contradiction last week but we need to use the Fundamental Theorem to show this instead of using the classical $p \cong q \mod (n)$.

The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic:
Every positive integer $n > 1$ can be represented in exactly one way as a product of prime powers:

I started out by using the proof by contradiction but I couldn't get very far.
Suppose $\sqrt3 \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then $\exists a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $\sqrt3 = a/b$.

I couldn't get far.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "how do you prove the square root of 3 using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic?"

Comment: Are the words "is irrational" supposed to be in here somewhere?

Comment: Yeah the question was: Show that square root of 3 is irrational using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmatics.

Comment: Next step: Then $a^2 = 3b^2$, which means that $3 \mid a$...

Comment: Square you equality, and suppose $a,b$  have no common factor, then use the Fundamental Theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\sqrt{3}$ is rational, assume $\sqrt{3}=\dfrac{a}{b}$, where $a,b$ are coprime integers. Then after rearranging and squaring we have,

$3b^2=a^2\qquad\ldots (1)$

By FTA, this implies that $a^2$ is divisible by $3$ and subsequently $a$ is divisible by $3$. Then we have $a=3k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then, using (1),

$3b^2=(3k)^2\implies 3b^2=9k^2\implies b^2=3k^2$

which implies (again by FTA) that $b^2$ is divisible by $3$, or $b$ is divisible by $3$.

Contradiction! We assumed that $a,b$ are coprime but this shows that they have a common prime factor of $3$.

Therefore, our assumption is wrong and hence $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational.

Note: It can also be seen that since $a,b$ are integers and $a^2,b^2$ must be perfect squares, then by (1) and FTA, $3$ divides $b^2$ an even number of times (because otherwise $b^2$ cannot be a perfect square) while it divides $a^2$ an odd number of times (because in LHS, an extra $3$ is multiplied to $b^2$). But then by equality in (1), it shows that $a^2$ is simultaneously divisible by $3$ odd and even number of times, which is impossible. So, our initial assumption that $\sqrt{3}$ is rational is wrong. As such, $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational.

Comment: The OP is required to use FTA, so you should *explicitly* mention it when you use it above.

Comment: @BillDubuque, I have edited my answer. It'd be great if you could verify it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: if $\sqrt{3}=a/b$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $3b^{2} = a^{2}$. Using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, count how many times $3$ can appear in the factorization of each side.

Comment: I don't get the hint.

Comment: @KagamineLen: by the FTA, suppose $3^{\alpha}\mid a$, and $3^{\beta}\mid b$. Then by the uniqueness of prime factorization guaranteed by the FTA, we have $2\alpha + 1 = 2\beta$. Do you see why? If so, why is this a problem?

Comment: I see it now.
Because p has a factorization of 3 times, but it should only factor once.

Comment: Hmmm? Are you sure you see? It's a parity argument. $3$ must divide $a$ an even number of times, but must divide $3b^{2}$ an odd number of times. This can't be so if they're equal.

Comment: I don't see it. Like how did you get 2a = 2b+1

Comment: @KagamineLen: ok! If you are still confused, feel free to comment. I am happy to try and explain things in a way that is clearer to you. (I may not respond instantly.)

Comment: The product of primes part I understand. Once we got to count how many times 3 appears in the factorization. I got lost. I know that I'm supposed to count the factorization. But How do I factorize a and b? What if a divides 3 an odd number of times and b divides 3 an odd number of times?

Comment: @KagamineLen: my apologies, a comment of mine above had a typo in it - it should have read $3$ must divide $a$ SQUARED an even number of times. It doesn't matter if $3$ divides $a$ an odd number of times, since $3$ must divide $a^{2}$ an even number of times. Do you understand this point?

Comment: ^I understand up to here. But what does divide by an even amount time mean?

Comment: Sorry if I ask so many questions but how did we get $\alpha$ to be even?

Comment: No apologies necessary, I keep making the same typo - I've deleted the comment to avoid confusion. $\alpha$ is not necessarily even. What I meant to say was, suppose $\alpha$ is the greatest integer such that $3^{\alpha}$ divides $a$. Then $(3^{\alpha})^{2} = 3^{2\alpha}$ divides $a^{2}$. This is the point.

Comment: ^This makes more sense. So $\alpha$ $\in$ $Z$ s.t. 3^2α divides a^2. Ok that makes sense.